# Sudden ORA-12516

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm working on a school assignment using an Oracle database provided by school (I cannot access the server configuration) and I suddenly got ORA-12516 errors whenever I perform any operation on the database.

I did not modify my code at all between when it still worked and it stopped working.

I cannot connect to the database using SQL developer or any other tool either.

I get the following error:

```
Error code: -2147467259
Error message: ORA-12516: TNS:listener could not find available handler with matching protocol stack
```

The Exception seems to be in my connect.Open():

```
string connectionstring = string.Format("Data Source= {0};User ID={1};Password={2};", host, username,
            password);
connect = new OracleConnection(connectionstring);
connect.Open(); // Exception is thrown here
```

I am 100% sure the connection string is correct as I can use the same info to connect using SQL developer.

This is my first request after starting the application, so I definitely do not have any other connections open.

How do I resolve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the error message please

Comment: @Sybren Sorry about that, I updated the question with the error.

Comment: remove the extra space in `Data Source= {0}`

Comment: @dotctor That doesn't fix the issue unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the database?

Comment: can you connect to the database using the same machine with sql developer?

Comment: @Sybren Unfortunately I cannot restart the database. I have very limited access since it's used by a lot of students.

Comment: @dotctor Yes, I can connect using SQL developer just fine.

Comment: Maybe the error pops up because the database is used by a lot of students and there a lot of connections.

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo in `host` value?

Comment: Ask the database admin to increase the value for `PROCESSES` in the `init.ora` file of the instance

Comment: from sql developer, run "select username, count(*) from v$session group by username" to see who is connected and how many people are connected

Comment: @Sybren I'm working on setting up a local db to see if that is indeed the cause.

Comment: @dotctor I am 100% sure the host value is correct, it worked 30 minutes ago and hasn't changed.

Comment: I can no longer use SQL developer to connect to the database. I think the server got overloaded by the excess of students trying to use it.

Comment: @cascer1 Ask the database admin to fix it then, because the problem is on his side

Comment: @Sybren They're working on it. I'm just using a local db for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by the big number of connections to the server all at once. This surge is probably caused by the fact that the exam just started.

Working on a local DB for now seems to be the only solution.